# Long-term variance of AR(p)

Tags: regression, time-series, variance, autocorrelation, autoregressive

According to the Yule-Walker equations, the long-term variance of an AR(p) process is $$\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi_1\rho_1 \ldots - \phi_p\rho_p}$$
Where the AR(p) is defined as $$Y_{t}=\delta + \phi_1 y_{t-1} \ldots + \phi_p y_{t-p} + \epsilon_t $$
with $\sigma^2$ denoting the variance of the white-noise process $\epsilon_t$ for all $ t$. The $\rho_t$ indicates the autocorrelation of $Y_t$ with $Y_{t-h}$.

The derivation of this result is given below.

Confusingly, my FRM-book states that the long-term variance of AR(p) is equal to:
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi_1 \ldots - \phi_p}$$
This indicates that all autocorrelations need to be 1, which can’t be right.

I also find results stating the long-term variance should be:
$$\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi_1^2 \ldots - \phi_p^2}$$
(For example: https://gregorygundersen.com/blog/2022/01/06/autoregressive-model/)

Which is correct?

Derivation long-term variance:
Let $\gamma_t$ be the autocovariance of
$Y_t$ with $Y_{t-h}$.
$$ \gamma_0=\phi_1\gamma_1 + \ldots + \phi_p\gamma_p +  \sigma^2$$
Using $\gamma_j=\rho_j\gamma_0$:
$$ \gamma_0= \phi_1\rho_1\gamma_0 \ldots + \phi_p\rho_p\gamma_0 + \sigma^2 $$